# Get the file path relatively

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, find

I have two directories A and B. Each one contains a zip.

How can I write the path of these two zip files into a text file?

Example for the directory system:

```
FILES/ONE/one.zip
FILES/TWO/two.zip
```

And I want to run the command from FILES directory

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I edited the question with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `find` command, with its output directed to a file, in the following way:

```
/tmp/FILES$ find . -name "*.zip" -print > outfile.txt
```

Find every file ended with `zip` inside the current folder (`FILES`) and print it path
The output of the `find` command is directed into a text file:

The content of the `outfile.txt` is:

```
/tmp/FILES$ cat outfile.txt 

./TWO/two.zip
./ONE/one.zip
```

> Note, if you'll execute the `find` command in one folder above the `FILES` folder, your output will include also the `FILES` part of the folder.

e.g. when find output is directed to `stdout`

```
/tmp$ find FILES -name "*.zip" -print
FILES/TWO/two.zip
FILES/ONE/one.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple shell globbing can achieve this. For example, given

```
$ tree .
.
├── ONE
│   └── one.zip
└── TWO
    └── two.zip

2 directories, 2 files
```

then

```
$ printf '%s\n' */*.zip
ONE/one.zip
TWO/two.zip
```

Redirect the output to a file by appending `> outfile` to the command. If you want to prepend `./` to make the relative path more explicit, change `%s` to `./%s`

```
$ printf './%s\n' */*.zip > outfile
$ cat outfile
./ONE/one.zip
./TWO/two.zip
```

If you want to do this *recursively*, then `bash` supports that if you have enabled the `globstar` shell option e.g.

```
$ cd ..
$ shopt -s globstar
$ printf '%s\n' **/*.zip
FILES/ONE/one.zip
FILES/TWO/two.zip
```

If you're using this in a script, you should probably enable the `nullglob` option as well, to properly handle the case in which no matching file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with `regex`

```
find /tmp/FILES -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/*/*.zip" > outfile.txt
```

Output is the same:

```
./TWO/two.zip
./ONE/one.zip
```

Issue is that it will match all the zip files in any subfolder. If you can define subfolders containing files you can do:

```
find /tmp/FILES -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(ONE|TWO)/*.zip" > outfile.txt
```